# GWT XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am using GWT. GWT is based on XMLHttpRequest. what is XMLHttpRequest and how GWT works?

```
XMLHttpRequest
```

Thanks!

Comment: ...seriously? A little broad, don't you think?

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions about actual problems you are currently facing. It is not for asking for tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very wide question.

It might be helpful if you read about [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) first.

[How GWT Works](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_HowGWTWorks)

Answer (score 0):

If I want to describe it very simple, we can say its a javascript object which transfers requests between browser and remote server without reloading entire webpage. It's internal implementation is browser native, but its known as heart of any AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And Xml) based technology such as GWT, jQuery and other similar frameworks.
See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) for more information.